# Joining child and parent tables

Tags: mysql, join

I am a newbie in mysql and I have a quick question about using the different join. Say for instance, I have 2 tables, one titled totals and another is titled goods and each contains values,

## goods

```
ID | Name
--------
1 | coffee
2 | tea
3 | chocolate
```

## totals

```
Quantity | goods ID
---------------------
40 | 3
20 | 2
10 | 1
```

Like this for example, the goods ID in total is the child of the ID of the goods table, but the display I want is

## totals

```
Quantity | goods ID
-------------------
40 | chocolate
20 | tea
10 | coffee
```

I just want to know where the different joins would be applicable.

Comment: See [this great explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: so apparently what i need is inner join?

Comment: select * from goods INNER JOIN totals ON goods.ID = totals.goods ID?

Comment: Depends on the request. Do you want to display all goods or just the goods that do contain a quantity?

Comment: For this data set inner, left, and right joins would all return the same thing because every id entry in the goods table also has an entry in the totals table and vice versa. Read the link juergen posted and try it yourself in MySQL workbench. That's the best way to learn. Just make a couple tables, stick some data in, and try some different joins.

Comment: @miguel inner join is the default; I never code it - just `select * from goods join totals ON goods.ID = totals.goods_ID`

Comment: sir @juergend Id want to display only those with quantity..

Comment: then use an inner join

Answer (score 0):

Following up from the link Juergen posted (that link is a very good reference), to achieve the result of the 3rd table you could use INNER JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN or LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN. The reason for this is because of the way your two tables are set up to match each other, hence there is no null values to worry about.

However, if the tables were set up like this:

## Goods

ID | Name
 --------
 1 | coffee
 2 | tea
 3 | chocolate
 4 | milk

## Totals

Quantity | goods ID
 ---------------------
 40 | 3
 20 | 2
 10 | 1

Then, to achieve the same result you would want to use an INNER join.