# vb.net datagridview display from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am using visual studio, and I am having trouble with datagridview, can I display a query that joins two tables in this datagridview?

For example, I already asked in here about the query that I have to try on merging two tables,

```
goods
id | name
1  | coffee
2  | tea
3  | choco
```

and

```
total
goodsID | quantity
3       | 40
2       | 20
1       | 10
```

and the display i want to see in the datagridview is

```
total
goods | quantity
choco | 40
tea   | 20
coffee| 10
```

I already searched on what query to use but when i add a query in the datagridview, I get an error saying "The schema returned by the new query differs from the base query". Is there anyway to fix this? Please help me, im trying to make a simple/practice vb forms program.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have so far....

Comment: I don't have any code, since I am using visual studio, I am only dragging and Dropping, but if you are asking about the query, so far I will try this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811751/joining-child-and-parent-tables?noredirect=1#comment59292241_35811751

Comment: There is a flaw in your db design.  If there is a one to one relationship between something in the "Goods" table and the StockLevel table, why would they be in different tables?

Comment: Yes sir you that is a flaw, and I noticed it awhile, but I am just actually, trying to learn using visual studio and I want to learn about joining tables in this software.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this INNER JOIN:

```
Select a.name,b.quantity from goods a inner join goodsquan b on a.id=b.goodsid
```

Note: goodquan table is your total table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

> SELECT g.name,t.quantity from goods g,total t where g.goodsid=t.id